# Bijections $\mathsf{Sh}(1, p+q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\simeq \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(1, P)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, functions, permutations

For integers $p, q\geq 1$ let us write $S_{p+q}$ for the set of bijections of the set $I_{p+q}:=\{1, \ldots, p+q\}$. This is a group with the usual composition of maps. Let us then define $$\mathsf{Sh}(p, q):=\{\sigma\in\mathsf{S}_{p+q}: \sigma(1)<\ldots<\sigma(p)\quad \textrm{and}\quad \sigma(p+1)<\ldots<\sigma(p+q)\}. $$ The elements in $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)$ are called **$(p, q)$-shuffles**. It is easily seen that the cardinality of $|\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)|$ of $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)$ is $$|\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)|=\binom{p+q}{q}. $$

So counting elements we see there are bijections:

$$\mathsf{Sh}(1, p+q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(1, p)$$

and

$$\mathsf{Sh}(1, p+q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(p, q+1)\times \mathsf{Sh}(1, q).$$

Can anyone help me construct those bijections explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can regard the $(p,q)$-shuffles in this way. Take a line of $p+q$ objects and colour $p$ or them red and $q$ of them blue. The corresponding
permutation lists the indices of the red objects in ascending order followed by the indices of the blue objects.

Take a line of $p+q+1$ objects, colour one of then yellow, $p$
of them brown and $q$ of them pink. If you replace yellow by red
and brown and pink both by blue, then you get a $(1,p+q)$ shuffle.
If you remove the yellow and replace browns and pinks by reds and blues
you get a $(p,q)$ shuffle. We can reverse the procedure. So we get
a bijection between these arrangements and
$\text{Sh}(1,p+q)\times\text{Sh}(p,q)$.

On the other hand we could replace yellow and brown by red and pink by blue, or remove the pinks and replace yellow by red and brown by blue.
This gives a bijection to $\text{Sh}(p+1,q)\times\text{Sh}(1,p)$.

With sufficient labour you could disguise these bijections by expressing
everything in terms of permutations.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll have to think a little about it =)

Comment: @PtF make that "$\cdots<\sigma(p+1)$ and $\sigma(p+2)<\cdots$".

Comment: Are you saying $\mathsf{Sh}(1, p+q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(p, q)$ and $\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(1, p)$ are in bijection with $\mathsf{Sh}(1, p, q)=\{\sigma\in S_{p+q+1}: \sigma(2)<\ldots< \sigma(p+1)\ \textrm{and}\ \sigma(p+2)<\ldots< \sigma(p+q+1)\}$?

Comment: In general we can define $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q, r):=\{\sigma\in S_{p+q+r}: \sigma(1)<\ldots< \sigma(p)\ \textrm{and}\ \sigma(p+1)<\ldots< \sigma(p+q)\quad \textrm{and}\ \sigma(p+q+1)<\ldots< \sigma(p+q+r)\}$..

Comment: @PtF Exactly! a three-way shuffle.

Comment: For $\sigma\in \mathsf{Sh}(1, p)$ define $\overline{\sigma}\in \mathsf{Sh}(1, p, q)$ leaving the last $q$ entries be identity. Then define $\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\times \mathsf{Sh}(1, p)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(1, p, q)$ setting $(\tau, \sigma)\longmapsto \tau\circ \overline{\sigma}$. Does that yield the bijection?